# Pandas column comparison so that two columns simultaneously are not equal to a value

Tags: pandas, python-3.8

I have a dataframe `df` as follows:

```
Col1    Val1    Val2   Val3
a       v1      v1     z1
b       v1      v3     x1
c       v2      v2     x2
```

I want get the following:

```
Col1    Val1    Val2   Val3
b       v1      v3     x1
c       v2      v2     x2
```

I tried the following:

```
df = df[df['Val1'] != 'v1']
df = df[df['Val2'] != 'v1']
```

But the above step gets me only third row of `df`. I only want to get rid of rows when both columns are not equal to `v1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you want to check that there is at least one column that is not v1 (using [`eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) and [`any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html)):

```py
df[df[['Val1', 'Val2']].ne('v1').any(1)]
```

or, using another syntax: not both columns are v1 (with using [`eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html), [`all`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) and the boolean NOT `~`):

```py
df[~df[['Val1', 'Val2']].eq('v1').all(1)]
```

output:

```
  Col1 Val1 Val2 Val3
1    b   v1   v3   x1
2    c   v2   v2   x2
```

Answer (score 2):

Check `any`

```
out = df[df[['Val1','Val2']].ne('v1').any(1)]
Out[338]: 
  Col1 Val1 Val2 Val3
1    b   v1   v3   x1
2    c   v2   v2   x2
```

Answer (score 1):

Chain both masks by `|` for bitwise `OR`:

```
df = df[(df['Val1'] != 'v1') | (df['Val2'] != 'v1')]
print (df)
  Col1 Val1 Val2 Val3
1    b   v1   v3   x1
2    c   v2   v2   x2
```